# error when using pygame.image.load()

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

When I try to load an image in another folder I get...

pygame.error: Couldn't open sprites/testtile.png

I can load .png files just fine if they are in the same directory, but once they're in another folder I get this error.

I know that python has access to that other folder as well, because I get no error importing .py files from the folded.

When I try pygame.image.get_extended it returns a 0, but loading .png files from the same directory gives me no problems, so I don't think that's what is causing this issue.

I am running PyCharm by the way, and things like this always seem to give me trouble with this IDE. I don't even think it's a pygame issue. No clue what to do at this point.

FOLDER STRUCTURE:

scripts/GraphicsDriver.py

sprites/testtile.png

the driver is trying to access the testile.png file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the sprites directory in the directory with GraphicsDriver.py?  You can run into some issues with the PyGame image loader.  It looks for files in the same directory as PyGame was initialized from.  Use 'os.path.join' to point it to the absolute path to your file.

I usually write my own little image loader around it though since it offers a little more flexibility to the process.  Something like this which will return the image and a rect:

```
def load_image(name, colorkey = None):
    """loads an image and converts it to pixels. raises an exception if image not found"""
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    except pygame.error, message:
        print 'Cannot load image:', name
        raise SystemExit, message
    image = image.convert()
    # set the colorkey to be the color of the top left pixel
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
    return image, image.get_rect()
```

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Thank for your help. I implemented your method and ran it as "testtile, testtile_rect = load_image('testtile.png')". This returned 'Couldn't open data\testtile.png' and 'Cannot load image: testtile.png'

Comment: fullname = os.path.join('data', name) can be changed to fullname = os.path.join('sprites', name)    sorry for the confusion.  I pulled this code from one of my scripts where I had my images in the data directory.

Comment: Yeah I tried a few different directories there, I figured data was a placeholder. It's still returning the same error unfortunately though.

Comment: It is returning two error, and one of them is  'Cannot load image: testtile.png'. Which is the same base error as with the normal method of importing. So I don't think it has anything to do with your method or what it fixes.

Comment: Hmmm, is the GraphicsDriver initializing PyGame, or is another script doing it? The code I gave you will look down from the initializing script, not up.  Try using the full image path, like fullname = C:\My_game\sprites\testtile.png  obviously changing the path to wherever it actually is.

Comment: The 'Cannot load image' error comes from the code I gave you, it prints that since it gets an exception from pygame.  'Couldn't open ....' is the pygame error.

Comment: So it all works when I use the full path. 'C:\...\sprites\image.png'. Is there a way I can reduce the work of typing that each time now that I know that path works?

Comment: Great! and Yes.  Is the sprites directory in the same directory as GraphicsDriver.py?  If it's not, consider simply moving your sprites directory there.  The previous code will work then.  Otherwise, you can move up to a parent directory with os.pardir like this:  fullname = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.pardir, 'sprites'), name)